# Conditional Probablity: Coins

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A fair coin is tossed 3 times.

1. Given the first tossing is a head, what is the probability to have three heads?
2. If you have been told that at least two of the tosses are heads, what is the probability to have a head in the first toss?

If someone could explain how to do this to me using a visualisation method (as in writing down the possible outcomes then deducing from there) I would gladly appreciate it.

Is question 1 just 0.5 x 0.5 = 0.25 since the results of the next 2 tosses are independent of the first?

For question 2, P(2 heads)= 4/8 and P(1st toss heads)=3/8 (given that there must be 2 heads), do I multiply them together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your remark on question 1 is okay. To find the answer on 2) you must divide P(1st toss head and at least 2 heads)$=\frac{3}{8}$ by P(at least 2 heads)$=\frac{4}{8}$. This gives you the conditional probability P(1st toss head | at least 2 heads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If the first tossing is a head then there are $4$ possibilities: HHH, HTH, HHT, HTT. They have equal probability to occur and in exactly $1$ of the possibilities (HHH) you have three heads. This amounts in a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$.

2) If at least two of the tossings are heads then there are $4$ possibilities: HHH, HHT, HTH and THH. They have equal probability to occur and in exactly $3$ of the possibilities (HHH, HHT and HTH) the first toss is a head. This amounts in a probability of $\frac{3}{4}$.